# NAs introduced by coercion when searching for punctuation characters in passwords for project

Tags: r

Hello I have a uni project I am working on. I need to search a list of passwords to see which of them have numbers or punctuation characters at the end of the password. I am then using R to create plots of the showing the counts on the y axis, and the punctation or number along the x axis with the number of times a password ends with that particular character.

I can get this to work for the numbers at the end, not for punctuation at the end. When I try with punctation I get error messages of NAs introduced by coercion. For some reason R is not recognising the punctuation.

The data I am using is

```
> Final_DF$Pswd
 [1] "monkey"       "iloveyou"     "dragon"       "jbI2pnK$xi"   "password"     "computer"     "!qessw"      
 [8] "tUNh&SSm6!"   "sunshine"     "wYrUeWV"      "superman"     "samsung"      "utoXGe6$"     "master"      
[15] "wjZC&OvXX"    "0R1cNTm9sGir" "Fbuu2bs89?"   "pokemon"      "secret"       "x&W1TjO59"    "buster"      
[22] "purple"       "shine"        "flower"       "marina"       "Tg%OQT$0"     "SbDUV&nOX"    "peanut"      
[29] "angel"        "?1LOEc4Zfk"   "computer"     "spiderman"    "nothing"      "$M6LgmQgv$"   "orange"      
[36] "knight"       "american"     "outback"      "TfuRpt3PiZ"   "air"          "surf"         "lEi2a$$eyz"  
[43] "date"         "V$683rx$p"    "newcastle"    "estate"       "foxy"         "ginger"       "coffee"      
[50] "legs" 


Final_DF$last.num <- as.numeric(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "[[:digit:]]$"))
last.num.factor <- factor(na.omit(Final_DF$last.num)) 

plot(last.num.factor, col="steelblue", main="Count By Last digit")
summary(last.num.factor) # plots graph

> Final_DF$last.num 
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  9 NA NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[38] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

The above data works / plots when I work with numbers, as you can see at position 20 we have a password ending with a 9 and at 26 a password ending with 0

```
Final_DF$last.punct <- as.numeric(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "[[:punct:]]$"))
last.punct.factor <- factor(na.omit(Final_DF$last.punct)) 

plot(last.punct.factor, col="steelblue", main="Count By Last punct")
summary(last.punct.factor)
```

When I try the same with punctuation it does work, problem seems to lie in the below command

```
> as.numeric(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "[[:punct:]]$"))
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[38] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

In this example I would expect passwords at position 8 would show last character is using ! and at position 17 the last character is ?

Any ideas how I resolve this issue please?

One last question I would like to do the same except to a graph for characters at beginning of password. using your logic I have the following code

```
fact5 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "^[[:punct:]]"))
fact6 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "^[[:digit:]]"))
fact7 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "^[[:lower:]]"))
fact8 <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "^[[:upper:]]"))

barplot(c(fact5, fact6, fact7, fact8))
```

However on the resulting bar chart there appears to be omissions from the x axis, looking at my password list the following characters appear to be missing p.w,F,b,T,n,$,e yet there is a plot of a bar for them, just a blank space on the x axis where there should be the character. Any ideas? Last question on this topic I promise - thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert punctuations like `?` or `!` to numeric which is giving you that error since R does not know how to convert `?` to a number. If you want to count number of punctuations or numbers use `table` and not `as.numeric`. For plotting you can use `barplot`.

```
library(stringr)
fact <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "[[:punct:]]$"))
barplot(fact)
```

To make this work for numbers you can use `fact <- table(str_extract(x, "[[:digit:]]$"))`.

---

To put both punctuations and digits in the same plot you can do :

```
fact1 <- table(str_extract(x, "[[:punct:]]$"))
fact2 <- table(str_extract(x, "[[:digit:]]$"))
barplot(c(fact1, fact2))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. `table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "[[:punct:]]$"))` gives me `! ? 
1 1 ` however plotting the graph does not work for punctuation. I could get it to work perfectly for numbers using the code in my original post. When I try to plot punctuation in just get 50 counts of 1 using my method or using you suggestion `barplot(Final_DF$last.punct)` I get a y axis of 0.0, 0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0 with lots of bars and no labels on x axis

Comment: Can you use my code as it is? I am not using `barplot(Final_DF$last.punct)`. What does running `fact <- table(str_extract(Final_DF$Pswd, "[[:punct:]]$"))` and `barplot(fact)` return to you?

Comment: apologies as you can probably tell im quite new to R. Yes your code works perfectly! Can you tell me is there a way to combine both digits (numeric) and punctation on the same x axis? With the count on the y axis?

Comment: @Marty See updated answer combining both of them in one plot.

Comment: Many thanks for all your help. I have posted one last question at the bottom of my original post if you would be so kind to take a look - I am guessing there is something I have overlooked

Comment: You should not edit/extend your question to ask more questions. Please ask a separate questions if you have additional question.